# Python _init_.py

Tags: python-3.x, youtube-api, web-crawler, httplib2

[HttpLib2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kojKo.png)

Can anyone tell me whats the issue here and how to solve it?
(https://github.com/Sunil02324/Youtube-Meta-Data-Comments-Scraper)

Comment: The github page in question has 2 python files. I suggest you mention what you ran. It is not apparent from the stack trace as well (screenshot). From the screenshot it looks like there are spaces in the URL that you are passing. So that could be an immediate thing you can look into.

Comment: i tried both script and got the same error

Comment: even if i try the script provided by google (https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/search.py) im getting the same error.